# Having Key Value Pair in C++ : <val1, val2> as key <frequency> as value

Tags: c++

I have a csv file that looks like the following:

```
ID L1 L2 L3 L4 X Y Z
1  3   3  1  2 f f x
1  3   3  3  2 g f f
2  3   4  4  3 o p q
```

I want to focus on Keeping (id, Li) where i = 1, 2, 3, 4 as key and frequency of occurrence as value, I want to create a table using c++ map that shows,

```
<1, 3> appeared 5 (i.e. where ever 1 was there 3 appeared in L1 and/or L2 L3 L4)
<1, 1> appeared 1
<1, 2> appeared 2
<2, 3> appeared 2
<2, 4> appeared 2
```

If there is a new entry, it gets added and the old one gets counted.

I am new to C++. I was able to implement this in python using `dict`. Using `std::map` in C++ seems to straight forward but I am not sure how to apply it to this situation!

Comment: So, `std::map<std::pair<<int, int>, int>` is what you want?

Comment: I think so. if it represents a table <id, li> <freq> then yes. I am having trouble in wrapping my mind around how to read the csv and take into account different columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to store 2 ints as a key and 1 as a frequency, this is how you do it

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>
```

In the above line:

```
pair< <int,int>, int>
```

can be understood as pair < key,value>.

While searching for a particular key you would need a pair of int. 
Eg: If you have stored <1,2>  =  <3> 
You would have to search with key = <1,2>

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> freq_data;

   freq_data[make_pair(1,3)] = 5;
   freq_data[make_pair(1,1)] = 1;
   freq_data[make_pair(1,2)] = 2;

   cout<<freq_data.at(make_pair(1,3))<<endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updated an example based on the table you provided.